# Custom Google map marker icon

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

So I am using gmap3 to dynamically load my map marker icon based on user image profile photo. Ideally, I want to have some custom styling on the marker icon image, and each marker icon image is different from user to user.

Here are two difficulties I have encountered:

1. Google map load marker icon as canvas (correct me if I am wrong), so it is not an image tag on DOM, thus I don't know how to add css styling to it
2. Even if it loads it as image, I couldn't find a way to define a callback function with gmap3 (and use jQuery to style the image selector) when the custom icon is completely loaded on DOM. (I tried `liveQuery`, it's a horrible idea, and I've tried `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function()`, which didn't work out well.

Here are some of my approaches:

1. I added `animation` property to the marker, and pass a random string to that (which should produce an error), and this makes icon loaded as an image tag on DOM.
2. I then use `setTimeout` (because I do not know where to define callback function on gmap3 after the marker is loaded) to select image css, and add a `background-image` css property to that transparent icon image, so I can have a custom user profile image on marker

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to apply css on a marker, you can try the following method to include `var marker = new MarkerWithLabel`. [**Link**](http://codepen.io/diana_aceves/pen/HjKdx)